# Does dolphindb have a SQL statement that can be executed successfully if I want to check all the IDs?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to query all the IDs. I wonder whether dolphindb have a SQL statement that can be executed successfully if I want to check all the IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following script:

```py
select distinct(id) from loadTable("library name", "table name") where date(time field) = 2021.08.24
```